# Can one get the expires time for a Facebook access token through the Omniauth Rubygem

Tags: facebook, token, omniauth

I'd like to store the expires time for my FB access tokens that are acquired by using the Omniauth gem, but I don't see an easy way to do that. It appears from looking at the Omniauth code (0.3.x) that the expires time is simply ignored by Omniauth and that some fairly deep customization would be required to get it.

Does anyone know the best way to do this or if it is possible/worth the trouble?

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe im wrong but did you try this?

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
expires_at = Time.at(auth['credentials']['expires_at'])
```

Comment: I was on an older version of Omniauth when I asked this question. I've since upgraded it, and this works fine. The hash member is ```auth['credentials']['expires_at']``` though.